# TPROXY iptables and l7 filter

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I am struggling with the TPROXY rule on mangle table, I configured this rules:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -m layer7 --l7dir /etc/l7-protocols --l7proto http -p tcp --dport 80  -j TPROXY --on-port 1035 --tproxy-mark 0xffff
ip rule add fwmark 0xffff lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

The http pattern reg expr contains this really simple gerexp:

```
.*
```

In this way all should match with that.

I wrote a program which open a sock_raw and print all  received packets, I tested it and it's works, I am sure about that.
What I see is that I cannot see the redirection caused by the TPROXY rule and in fact it redirect nothing, I think.

Have you any suggestion ?Maybe I misunderstand some iptable or l7filter rule and my problem is really simple.

Thanks a lot in advance!
Pietro.

Answer (score 0):

TPROXT target require that one port is listen at the requested TCP port, after a deep debug (which included some printk!!), tried with :

```
nc -l -p 1035
```

Packets is redirected, without is dropped.